# How to console.log props in React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React and have been thrown in the deep end with a task.

I must adjust the data for a date props. This looks (as far as I can tell) like:

```
form.defaultProps = {
  conf: {},
  minDate: new Date(),
  maxDate: new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() + 2)),
};
```

I want to test if `maxDate` is the prop I am after. To do that I want to `console.log` (or equivalent) its output.

Would anyone know how I should be doing this?

Comment: `console.log(form.defaultProps.maxDate)` ?

Comment: you'll want to run your `console.log` in one of the component lifecycle functions if you're just poking around.

Comment: Why don't you use something like [React Developer Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en) to inspect the props?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to just log it directly:

```
console.log(form.defaultProps);
```

Most likely, you might want to this within the `form` component you are creating by calling `console.log(this.props)`.

Answer (score 3):

As others are saying, you can simple do `console.log(this.props)` somewhere. I usually put it in the `render()` function so that every time there's an update to props or state, it will be logged again.

But if your sole purpose is to examine the props values for development, I'd recommend you to use [React Devtools extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en).